# duplicate a role using T-sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a users table with a list of users  with a role assigned to project, i would like to duplicate a users role to a new user.

**Example**

John is a user assigned to multiple project having different level of roles, i would like to copy john profile by creating a new user henry.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3363d) example of my table.

**Therefore the final result should be**

```
EMP_ID  USERNAME    Role    PROJECT
--------------------------------------------    
5       Henry           Admin   Test1
5       Henry           superuser   Test2
```

Comment: I sure hope this isn't your actual `[users]` table.  Because it's really a `[user-project-roles]` table, or a `[user-projects]` table at best.

Comment: Yeah, not seeing a primary key on your table definition.  This definitely isn't normalized.  Which, among other problems, is going to play havoc with any logical attempts to Update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result in 2 ways which are:

```
`
CREATE TABLE #users
([Emp_ID] int, [username] varchar(255), [Role] varchar(255)
     , [Project] varchar(255))
 ;

    INSERT INTO #users
([Emp_ID], [username], [Role],[Project])
     VALUES
   (1,'John','Admin','Test1'),
   (2,'Tim','user','Test3'),
   (3,'Jack','user','Test4'),
    (4,'John','superuser','Test2');
 Select * from #users

INSERT INTO #users
([Emp_ID], [username], [Role],[Project])
Select 5,'Henry', Role, Project 
from #Users where Emp_ID in (1,4)

or 
Select 5,'Henry', Role, Project 
from #Users where Username='John'
 `
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've assigned different Emp_IDs to John as a mistake in your example, I would write it as follows;

```
INSERT INTO users
SELECT 5, 'Henry', Role, Project
FROM Users
WHERE Emp_ID = 1 -- John's Emp_ID
```

-- If not a mistake

```
WHERE Emp_ID IN (1,4)
```